# Data Extension Systemtime

Tags: marketing-cloud

When using the "use current system time" function in a Data Extension date field, it always uses the american timezone date with US-Format, even when changing the account Timezone under System Preferences. Is there a way to adjust the time that will be saved in DE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the system time used for the default value for Data Extension date fields is always Central Standard Time (UTC minus six hours). There is no way of changing the Timezone used, although there are ways to manipulate that date time in landing pages, emails and the likes using AMPScript.

Comment: Unless you're account is on Stack 4, which is in US Mountain time (UTC minus 7 hours).